# How to create a permalink based on the text entered (using PHP code)

Tags: permalinks

My code is like this

```
<script> 
function doDashes2(str) {
    return str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi, '-').replace(/^-*|-*$/g, '').toLowerCase();
}
str="this permalink! __is_ created, using javascript (jQuery)";
alert(doDashes2(str));

</script>
```

The output comes as "this-permalink-is-created-using-javascript-jquery"

Can anybody suggest, how to do it using PHP

Answer (score 1):

use this.

```
function sterilize($title)
{
    $result = strtolower($title);
    // strip all non word chars
    $result = preg_replace('/\W/', ' ', $result);
    // replace all white space sections with a dash
    $result = preg_replace('/\ +/', '-', $result);
    // trim dashes
    $result = preg_replace('/\-$/', '', $result);
    $result = preg_replace('/^\-/', '', $result);

    return $result;
}
```